# What is the expansion for $\frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

What is the expansion for $\frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}$?
I know expansion for 
$$\begin{align}&(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+\dots\\
&(1+x)^{-2}=1+(-2)x+(-2)\frac{-3}{2!}+(-2)(-3)\frac{-4}{3!}+\dots\\
&(1+x^{2})^{-1}=1-x^{2}+x^{4}-x^{6}+\dots\end{align}.$$
But for $\frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}$ I got problem.
Can someone derive $\frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}$ term expansion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $|x|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^{3}}=(1-x)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots).$$

Comment: thank u.Can u explain how u got $\frac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^{3}}$

Comment: @Elizabeth  $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^3)$, so $1 - x^3 = (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2)$, as you can check by direct multiplication.

Comment: @Elizabeth Just verify that $1 - x^3 = (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2)$. More generally $1 - x^n = (1 - x)(1 + x +\dots+ x^{n-1})$